# C# parse object into Google BigQuery row

Tags: c#, google-bigquery

I'm very new with Google Big Query and I have a hard time inserting a row into a table.

For example I have a table:

```
iso2 [string|required]
names [record|required]
names.name [string|required]
names.language [string|required]
names.official [boolean|required]
```

And I have a class:

```
class Country{
   string Iso2 {get;set;}
   List<CountryName> Names {get;set;}

   class CountryName{
      string Name {get;set;}
      string Language {get;set;}
      bool Official {get;set;
   }
}
```

And I create a country

```
var country = new Country(){
   Iso2 = "nl",
   Names = new Country.CountryName(){
      Name = "Nederland",
      Language = "nl",
      Official = true
   }
}

BigQueryClient client = BigQueryClient.Create(projectId);
//How do I insert this country into the table?
```

So how do I convert an object so it can be inserted into Google BigQuery

Comment: You need to perform that conversion yourself. There's an example of insertion at https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2/latest/index.html#data-insertion. Have you *tried* creating a `BigQueryInsertRow` based on your object? What happened? Have you already created the table? What does the schema look like?

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes. I can use
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(country);
var dictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
var row = new BigQueryInsertRow();

That works fine for normal columns. Except for `record` columns.

Comment: I probably wouldn't go via JSON to be honest. It shouldn't be too hard to write your own converter, which should be able to handle record columns (I believe) - have you tried that?

Comment: Thnx, I will do that. I thought maybe a method existed.

Answer (score 0):

You can find [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples/tree/5bdd518fefcdc972ac4d2832c2f3f5ce13b173b1/bigquery/api/Snippets) some official snippets of `C#` code regarding `BigQuery` `SDK`.
In the file [TableInsertRows.cs](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples/blob/5bdd518fefcdc972ac4d2832c2f3f5ce13b173b1/bigquery/api/Snippets/TableInsertRows.cs) you can find the following example:

```
using Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2;
using System;

public class BigQueryTableInsertRows
{
    public void TableInsertRows(
        string projectId = "your-project-id",
        string datasetId = "your_dataset_id",
        string tableId = "your_table_id"
    )
    {
        BigQueryClient client = BigQueryClient.Create(projectId);
        BigQueryInsertRow[] rows = new BigQueryInsertRow[]
        {
            // The insert ID is optional, but can avoid duplicate data
            // when retrying inserts.
            new BigQueryInsertRow(insertId: "row1") {
                { "name", "Washington" },
                { "post_abbr", "WA" }
            },
            new BigQueryInsertRow(insertId: "row2") {
                { "name", "Colorado" },
                { "post_abbr", "CO" }
            }
        };
        client.InsertRows(datasetId, tableId, rows);
    }
}
```

I hope it helps